# I really need this python code explanation

Tags: python, recursion

I have a code in python that uses amount and coins change array as parameters and based on a possible number of combinations of the coins to be used to provide the money or amount to be given as complete indepth. but the issue here is that I seem not to have a clue how this recursion works

I already found the working code but I need some explanation about how thos works since I got this with my code called `countChange(4, [1,2])`.
The issue here is how does it work because I noticed with the code below , 
the amount started reducing and the the array was zero

```
def countChange(amount, coins):
    if (amount == 0):
        print("amount is 0", amount, coins)
        return 1
    elif (amount < 0 or coins == []):

        print("amount is less than 0 or empty coins array", amount, coins)
        return 0
    else:
        countChange(amount, coins[:-1])
        print("first called")
        countChange(amount - coins[-1], coins)
        print("second called")

countChange(4, [1,2])
```

I really dont undertand how come this correct result happens.

```
from python3 myprogram_name.py
amount is less than 0 or empty coins array 4 []
first called
amount is less than 0 or empty coins array 3 []
first called
amount is less than 0 or empty coins array 2 []
first called
amount is less than 0 or empty coins array 1 []
first called
amount is 0 0 [1]
second called
second called
second called
second called
first called
amount is less than 0 or empty coins array 2 []
first called
amount is less than 0 or empty coins array 1 []
first called
amount is 0 0 [1]
second called
second called
first called
amount is 0 0 [1, 2]
second called
second called
```

as it goes back and forth

Comment: The only way to understand how this works is to pretend you are the Python interpreter, and walk through the code step by step. Pay attention to when you come to a recursive call: Every call starts with a fresh copy of variables, with the new values. Enjoy!

Comment: yes sir, but I find out that with the variable passed. I get first 4 then an empty array , then afterwards the 4 starts reducing by 1, with coins array set to zero, I understand that recursion takes steps and the first called is called first until it meets a certain condition then it continues to the next but I dont seem to get why it goes forth and back it to the first then second and back to the first, then how come the first starts with 4 and empty array then 4 keeps reducing. Even as the intepreter I still am human in this thinking

Comment: I suggest to use Visual Studio Code for debugging. Debugging in there is pretty easy. Copy/paste the code there in a script file, add a breakpoint in the beginning of the code, go to debug section and start debugging line by line. Pick a pair of paper and pencil if you want. It would be much easier than someone explain it to you.

Comment: I have been doing this so thats why I asked I need an expert to explain what is going on, because I need to understand so as to know how to use this code in other similar issues more efficiently.

Comment: Can any body please help explaining , the code is correct but I dont uderstand how it works. At least give me a hint why it shows 4 and epty array in the first called recursive function, then I will attempt to carry on from ther

Comment: I don't think the code is correct: The last `else`has no function result and I can't recognize, how the recursion results are combined. In total this looks like a theoretical example forcefully using recursion, where iteration would be easier.

Comment: @guidot The "function result" is never used, it is not needed. But the error message is nonsense since it is triggered during normal operation. The code is a little silly, I agree, but it is (almost) serving its purpose in forcing the OP to take a close look at the code.

Comment: @optimus, You did not single-step the code, you are just looking at the output. But the very first output is produced after several recursive calls to the function (the line just above ("first called"). Pretend to be the interpreter, go step by step, and don't cut any corners; you'll be surprised.

Answer (score 0):

At first time,

```
countChange(4, [1,2])
```

the amount is not zero, and the coins array was not empty, else statement gets worked. Inside the else statement, there is a recursion call with,

```
countChange(4, [1])-------->opened
```

then again comes into else statement, and again recursion called,

```
countChange(4, [])----->opened
```

Now comes to the elif statement, prints the string and return zero called.so the final call of recursion going to be ended.

```
countChange(4, [])------>ended..
```

still we have remains three statement on that else block.

```
print("first called")
countChange(amount - coins[-1], coins)
print("second called")
```

So according to that, the "first called" string gets printed.And again we have a recursive call, Now we subtract the amount value by counts[-1], so amount = 4 - 1 = 3.

```
countChange(3, [1])----->opened
```

Similar to again, else statement gets activated, and again having a recursive call,

```
countChange(3, [])----->opened
```

This way, if you trace recursion, you can get cleared.,
Hope this helps you:)